# speed up AUC calculation

Tags: r, auc

I would like to speed this for loop up.

```
library(MESS)

integrate<-function(y){
  x=1:length(y)
  lst<-c()
  for (i in 1:length(y)){
    lst=c(lst,auc( x[0:i],y[0:i]))
  }
  return(lst)
}
```

edit; The AUC function needs to be rewritten probably, perhaps an alternative is already available that could do this in-house?